# Retrieve child data from firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have restructured my firebase database to a flat model in which object are referenced from one object to another. Like in the example below I reference related users from the customer object based on on their id's.

Now for some reason I expect the the data of the user objects to be returned when I list the 'customer/1510925e-0541-474f-93c1-10890934fda9' path.

What is the logic to access the user data when listing the customer record? What am I missing here?

```
  "customer" : {
    "1510925e-0541-474f-93c1-10890934fda9" : {
      "users" : {
        "LlMNVWXvzLhmP24AKVciM2PvPVy2" : true,
        "Q4sM188BgwRGYhJUiLDqgAzGGX72" : true
      },
      "name" : "NiceCustomer"
    },
    "634f6b10-1def-496d-af44-834ae3c69c27" : {..customer2.},
    "a7ca5d01-757c-4534-a9e1-154c53d160a7" : {..customer 2 etc.}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you also have a path for your user data, such as "/users/". The data for the user record would therefore be returned by looking at  "users/LlMNVWXvzLhmP24AKVciM2PvPVy2", for example.

The point of indexing your records as you've done by indicating which users are associated with a customer is just to make it easier to fetch data later on, particularly as your database scales.

Imagine that your user data looked like this:

```
"users":{
  "LlMNVWXvzLhmP24AKVciM2PvPVy2":{
    "customer" : "1510925e-0541-474f-93c1-10890934fda9"
  }
  "Q4sM188BgwRGYhJUiLDqgAzGGX72":{
    "customer" : "634f6b10-1def-496d-af44-834ae3c69c27"
  }
  ...for many, many records...
}
```

...and you need to find which user(s) belong(s) to a particular customer record. If your list of users is large, it's going to take a lot of processing to find all the relevant records. You have to check each user.

If, on the other hand, you've done some indexing as you've indicated in your question, finding which users go with a customer record is easy. Just pull up the customer record, get the user ids, then get their data from the /users path.

See the Firebase docs for a great description: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout

Comment: Yep I have a user path like you indicate. I start to get it. Suppose I would like fetch all users from a specific customer I have to fetch the customer record ('customer/<customerkey>'). Then I have the customer record but how do I fetch the list of users for that specific customer. Is it by fetching the records on the 'users/' path using the list of users from the  'customer/<customerkey>'/users array? 
So this will be two calls right? it is normal that the user records are not returned in the first fetch?

Comment: It is normal that the user records are not returned with a fetch against your 'customer' path. And yes, one possible way to do that query would be to first get the customer record, then use the list of users to query the '/user' path to get further data. One description I like on how to find records using the Firebase database is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries